# NLP question: How to do inference in not popular languages?

Tags: nlp

If someone would like to do inference in a language which is not as popular as English or is dead, like ancient Greek, how can do it?

One approach that I have in my mind is the following:

1. You have texts from non_popular language
2. Translate it to English
3. Apply an NLP model to English and give labels to the non_popular language texts based on this output.

What are your thoughts about this approach? Do you know if there is any research using this way of thinking?